# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, jax-rs

I get the below build error in Eclipse Oxygen whenver I try to edit the files and save the changes.

[image]

```
Building workspace has encountered a problem.
Errors occurred during build.

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project 'EmployeesManagementSystem'.
Unknown tag! pos=4 poolCount = 18
```

I have tried deleting the `.metadata` folder of the eclipse workspace(as suggested in other posts related to build error) , but the error is still there.

Answer (score 21):

It's possible that some of jar files in your local maven repository, which are used by your project, was not downloaded correctly or it's corrupted. You can:

1. try to clean your local maven repo by `Maven > Update project > Check "Clean projects"` and the project for which you apply clean action
2. disable it (if you don't need CDI Tools support) in `Window > Preferences > JBoss Tools > Maven Intagration > Uncheck "CDI Facet"` and then disable in `Project Properties > CDI Settings > Uncheck "CDI Support"` for your project as well

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dino, for your suggestions.
I have already tried the first option. But that doesn't seem to solve the problem. I still keep getting the same error dialogue.
As for the second suggestion, yes that did stop the error dialogue from appearing, but what if I want the CDI support also, as its really helpful as far as the code-completions are concerned.

Comment: There is an error in:
Window > Preferences > JBoss Tools > Maven Intagration > Uncheck "CDI Facet"
It´s Window > Preferences > JBoss Tools > JBoss Maven Integration > Uncheck "CDI Facet"
I lost various hours because that.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try to check (uncheck if already checked) "CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection)" in the Project Facets dialog and click "Apply and Close".
Than execute "Update Project..." (Maven menu of the project). You might get the error once again. Reopen the Project Facets dialog and uncheck (check if unchecked) "CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection)", than apply and close. The error should disappear.

Comment: 2. step solved my problem. Thanks a lot!!