# Getting 'Building workspace' error when I save any file in the project

Tags: java, eclipse, assertj

I have added a new dependency in my project which works great. but whenever I build or save any file in my project I get the following error. I use command line maven to run the project and I dont see any problem with the project itself, it works as expected. But this error is very annoying. [error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwYDg.png)

The following json-unit-assertj dependency is causing this error:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-unit-assertj</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If I remove it from the project the error goes away. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48582218/10226142)? I don't know which components provides CDI; are you using recent releases?

Comment: Yes I have tried. But no luck. I don't want turn off CDI support so didn't try second option in that answer. Looks like this issue is related to the dependency itself.